# Questions about a commutative ring with exactly three ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Assume that $R$ has exactly three distinct ideals: $\{0\},I, R.$
>
> 1) Show that if $a \in R-I$, then $a$ is a unit in $R$.
>
> 2) Let $a,b\ne0$ in $I$. Show that $ab=0$.

Comment: Since I don't want to meet a low-effort question with a low-effort solution, I will mention two high-effort sledgehammers that do the job since they are amusing. 1) If $I^2=I$, the ring is semiprime, hence semisimple Artinian. As a product of $n$ fields, it must have $2^n$ different ideals, never $3$.  2) If $I^2=I$, the ring is von Neumann regular. Since it is also local, it must be a field, but this contradicts $I\neq \{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT for 1: $Ra$ is an ideal containing $a$, so what can we say about $Ra$?

HINT for 2: Consider the ideal generated by $ab$.

Comment: Does $Ra$ means $\{ra:r\in R \}$?

Comment: @user236626, yes the ideal generated by $a$.

Comment: could you give me more details?

Comment: @user236626 Since $Ra$ contains an element not in $I$, and $R$ only has 3 idals, what does $Ra$ equal to?

Comment: @user236626 $Ra = R$, but then $1 \in Ra$, so what do we know then?

Comment: there exist $c \in R$ such that $ac=1$

Comment: @user236626, so $a$ is a unit, which proves part 1. Try to prove 2) on your own now by considering the ideal generated by $ab$, that is  $Rab$.

Answer (score -2):

$\underline{\text{Part 1.}}$  Let $a\in R-I$, in particular this means that $a\neq 0$ since $0\in I$.  Now take the principal ideal generated by $a$, I'll write as $(a)=aR$.  This is an ideal and a subset of $R$.  Since $1\in R$ we have that $1\cdot a\in(a)$ which means that $(a) \neq I$ because $a\notin I$.  Also, $(a)\neq (0)$ since $a\neq 0$.  Therefore, we must have that $(a)=R$.

This tells us that $1\in (a)$, so for some ring element $r\in R$ we have,
$$r a=1 $$

and thus $a$ is a unit.

$\underline{\text{Part 2.}}$ Let $a,b\neq 0$ be elements of $I$.  Take the principal ideal generated by the element $ab$, which I will write as $(ab)$.  Since $ab\in I$ by the ideal property, we have that $(ab)\subset I$.  Since $(ab)$ is an ideal, this means we have two choices, either $(ab)=(0)$ or $(ab)=I$.

By way of contradiction, assume that $(ab)=I$.  Since $a\in I $ this means that $a\in (ab)$.  So for some $r_1\in R$ we have,
$$a=abr_1=a(br_1) $$

This implies that $b r_1=1$.  So $b$ is a unit.  But we also that that $b\in (ab)=I$, and any ideal containing a unit is the whole ring.  We know that $R$ and $I$ are distinct ideals though.  Contradiction.  Therefore, our assumption that $(ab)=I$ was incorrect.  So we are only left with the option that $(ab)=(0)$, thus $ab=0$.

Comment: It is unclear how you're drawing the conclusion that $a=abr_1$ implies $br_1=1$. It's true here since the ring is local, but nothing like that is hinted at. It certainly isn't true for other rings.

Comment: R is not given to be an integral domain or a field so cancellation law may not  hold.