# Basic ring question about the identity and a question

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with a $1$. If $a \in R$ (not necessarily arbitrary) satisfies $a=abc$ for some $b,c \in R$ then is $bc=1_R$?

Edit: For the second part of the question linked, we shall answer it here.

Question: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ with exactly three ideals: the zero ideal, $I$ and $R$. 
Show that if $a,b\in I$ then $ab=0$.

Attempt:

If either $a$ or $b$ is zero then $ab=0$.
So we may as well assume that both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero. We know that $abR = I$ or $\{0\}$. Suppose it were $I$. Then since $a\in I$ we may write $abc=a$ for some $c\in R$. This shows that $a(bc-1)=0$. Since $b\in I$ we have, by closure of $I$, that  $bc\in I$. This then tells us that $bc-1\notin I$ or else $1\in I$. Thus $bc-1$ must be a unit since $I=R\setminus U(R)$, and so there is a $v \in R$ with $(bc-1)v=1$, and multiplying through by $a$ yields $a=a(bc-1)v=0v=0$, contradicting the fact that $a\ne0$. Thus our assumption that $abR=I$ must be false and we conclude that $abR$ must have had been the zero ideal. And this gives $ab=0$.

Comment: No, but it is true for $a\neq 0$ in a ring with a unique maximal ideal (which is the context of the question you alluded to below.)

Comment: $bc\neq 1$ does not necessarily imply that $b$ is not a unit. How do you know that there cannot be some $d$ with $bd=1$? In any case, you don't need this to conclude that $b \in I$. The latter is given as a hypothesis. P.S. Why are you answering [the question from the other thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639870/questions-about-a-commutative-ring-with-exactly-three-ideals) here?

Comment: What do you mean the result is clearly true if a or b is $0$? If $b=0$, $1=bc=0$ is a contradiction. If $a=0$, $abc=a$ holds for any $bc$ at all, even when you pick it to be a nonunit. So it is clearly *false* in these cases.

Comment: Hopefully the above edit is now correct.

Comment: That's now an answer, provided that it is acceptable for you to assume $U(R)=R\setminus I$. You could clarify, using that, why $b\in I$, which is not very well justified at the moment

Comment: $b$ is in $I$ by hypothesis of the question.

Comment: Part (a) tells you that $R \setminus I \subset U(R)$. You are asserting that $R \setminus I = U(R)$ (equivalently, $I = R \setminus U(R)$). For completeness you should probably mention that the reverse containment $U(R) \subset R \setminus I$ holds because $I$ is a proper ideal, hence cannot contain a unit. In any case, your proof only requires $R \setminus I \subset U(R)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: let $R=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, $a=b=c=2$. Then $abc=2=a$, but $bc=4\neq 1$.

If however $R$ is a domain, then $a=abc$ implies that $a(1-bc)=0$, hence if $a\neq 0$ then $bc=1$ since $R$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: Does that mean the second answer to the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639870/questions-about-a-commutative-ring-with-exactly-three-ideals (in Part 2) used a faulty argument? If so, how do I approach it ?

Comment: @satokun Yes, the step in the proof you mention is unclear (however it is true in a ring with a unique maximal ideal, which is the case in that problem.) If you had included any effort in that question I would have explained in a solution; however, I am going to ignore it since it is in "question-dump-format". If you improve it, feel free to ping me.

Comment: @rschwieb Please check my edit. I realize it may not be the most elegant answer, but I do hope its correct !